# VirtualHost settings mac apache reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, apache, express, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I am trying to deploy a `node express` app on my Apache server running on a Mac.

If I navigate to `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/:8000` I see the website and everything works as expected.

However, from my research I realise I need to set up a reverse proxy, but not sure am I missing some steps required to set this up.

My goal is that when a user navigates to `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/website` that they will be redirected to `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/:8000`as this is where the `express` app is running.

By navigating to on the Mac server sudo `nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` I have set up the following VirtualHost settings.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /website http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/:8000
  ProxyPassReverse /website http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/:8000
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this correct? Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Just to make it clear my `app.js` file looks like this

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
})
```